# .apk file works on Emulator but not in real android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am facing a weird problem. I've developed a react-native app in 'Expo' and generate its .apk file following (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/building-standalone-apps.html#building-standalone-apps) this guideline. Now the downloaded .apk file works well on 'Emulator' but in real android phone Error: `App not installed. The package appears to be corrupt` ....?

Comment: Which 'Emulator' (the one from Android SDK?) and which device are you talking about?